# Replace matching date with corresponding date in duplicated row in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, replace

In the following data, I would like to replace any GrDate with the value of "6/1/2020" with the corresponding GrDate value for the same person (Nb).

So for Nb = 100, I would like to replace the "6/1/2020" "10/20/2019".

200 are OK, no "6/1/2020" date.

For Nb=300, I would like to replace the "6/1/2020" "7/29/2018".

What is the best R logic

[image]

```
# Load required library
library(lubridate)

# Create the data frame
df <- data.frame(
 Nb = c(100, 100, 200, 200, 300, 300),
 Name = c("Peter Falk", "PeterFalk", "Chris Jones", "Chris Jones", 
          "Jack Walsh", "Jack Walsh"),
 GrDate = c("10/20/2019", "6/1/2020", "8/5/2012", "1/7/2024", 
           "6/1/2020", "7/29/2018"),
 Jdate = c("10/20/2019", "11/26/2023", "8/5/2012", "1/7/2024", 
           "11/26/2023", "3/10/2019"),
  G = c(76, 76, 83, 85, 76, 76)
)

# Convert GrDate and Jdate columns to Date type
df$GrDate <- mdy(df$GrDate)
df$Jdate <- mdy(df$Jdate)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
df |>
  mutate(
    GrDate = if_else(GrDate == '2020-06-01', first(GrDate[GrDate != '2020-06-01']), GrDate),
    .by = Nb
  )
#    Nb        Name     GrDate      Jdate  G
# 1 100  Peter Falk 2019-10-20 2019-10-20 76
# 2 100   PeterFalk 2019-10-20 2023-11-26 76
# 3 200 Chris Jones 2012-08-05 2012-08-05 83
# 4 200 Chris Jones 2024-01-07 2024-01-07 85
# 5 300  Jack Walsh 2018-07-29 2023-11-26 76
# 6 300  Jack Walsh 2018-07-29 2019-03-10 76
```

Comment: Thanks, but not correct, here all 2020-06-01 are replaced by 2019-10-20, that is only correct for the first person, the second person has no 2020-06-01 date so no change necessary. The last person should replace its 2020-06-01 value with 2018-07-29

Comment: Perhaps you just need to add `.by = Nb`...for example: `df |> mutate(GrDate = if_else(GrDate == '2020-06-01', first(GrDate[GrDate != '2020-06-01']), GrDate), .by = Nb)`

Comment: This worked, brilliant. Thank you both for solving this problem.

Comment: Oops, forgot the grouping. Thanks Ben, edits made!